# Both ipython and ipython3 shows "Python 3.5.2"

Tags: ipython

If I invoke `ipython` and `ipython3`, both show exactly the same message:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Is not it that `ipython` shows something like Python 2?

How can I make `ipython` use Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

IPython 6+ requires Python 3.3+, so that's what it defaults to, and it will not open Python 2.x.

From the [6.x Series page](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version6.html) in the IPython docs:

> #### Important
>
> This documentation covers IPython versions 6.0 and higher. Beginning
> with version 6.0, IPython stopped supporting compatibility with Python
> versions lower than 3.3 including all versions of Python 2.7.
>
> If you are looking for an IPython version compatible with Python 2.7,
> please use the IPython 5.x LTS release and refer to its documentation
> (LTS is the long term support release).